# MVC5 simple ajax request stuck

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

iv read several posts about ajax calls and im still confused.

My HomeControler got methods

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string srchterm)
public async Task Publish(TrendVM trendVm)
```

I want to call Publish it from index.cshtml

my view is like this

```
@model IEnumerable<Trend>

<div class="container-fluid post-container">
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var trend in @Model)
         {
             Html.RenderPartial("_Trend",trend);
             //button that calls Publish and passes it trend without refreshing the page.
         }
    }
</div>
```

is the some razer helper that will generate the request?

Comment: so where is your ajax call?

Comment: I dont undestand how it should look like

Comment: i believe you are trying to call `Publish` inside loop. You can make your method i.e `Publish` as `public async Task<ActionResult> Publish(TrendVM trendVm)` and call it as a child action such as `@Html.Action("Publish", trend)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recommended approach**

If you have a unique record id for each trend item you are printing, you should use that id to pass it back to your server via ajx.

```
foreach (var trend in @Model)
{
   Html.RenderPartial("_Trend",trend);

   @Html.ActionLink("Publish","Publish","Home",new { id=trend.Id},
                                                 new { @class="publishLink"}) 


}
```

Basically, the above code will render an anchor tag like this for each trend item

```
<a href="Home/Publish/450">Publish</a>
```

where *450* will be replaced with the actual unique Id you have for trend item. Clicking on the link will open the url in a new page usually. I don't think you want that to happen here. So we will override the default click behaviour and make an ajax call to server.

Add this script to your page

```
@section Scripts
{
  <script>
     $(function(){
         $("a.publishLink").click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            var url=$(this).attr("href");

            $.post(url,function(response){
              alert("Publish completed");
            });

         });
     });
 </script>    
}
```

Now we need to make sure our publish method accepts an id and do the processing. So change the `Publish` method to /Create a new method (and use that method name in our earlier markup in `Html.ActionLink` call)

```
public async Task Publish(int id)
{
  // using the Id value, do some processing.
}
```

But if you do not want to change your Publish method signature, what you should be doing is creating a form inside your foreach loop and serialize the form and send it. You need to keep the data you want to send in input form fields. We will keep those in hidden fields for now.

```
foreach (var trend in @Model)
{
   Html.RenderPartial("_Trend",trend);
   using(Html.BeginForm("Publish","Home"))
   {
     @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.Name)
     @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.TrendCode)

     @Html.ActionLink("Publish","Publish","Home",new { id=trend.Id},
                                                 new { @class="publishLink"})
   }

}
```

Assuming `Name` and `TrendCode` are 2 properties of your TrendVM.
and the javascript will be

```
@section Scripts
{
  <script>
     $(function(){
         $("a.publishLink").click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            var _f=$(this).closest("form");

            $.post(_f.attr("action"),_f.serialize(),function(response){
              alert("Publish completed");
            });

         });
     });
 </script>    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write some js code. And use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function. Put a button on your View:

```
<button id="your-submit-button" type="submit">Ajax call</button>
```

Put empty `div` somewhere on page where you will put your PartialView:

```
<div id="your-partial-view-container"></div>
```

Then put some jquery (you also can use plain old js, but it's easier with jquery) on your page. It's better to put all your js code in `@section script {}` that defined in your `_Layout`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#your-submit-button").click(function(){
           $.ajax({
                url: @Url.Action("Publish","Home"), //here you put your controller adress
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'html',
                data: $("#your-form-with-model-data-id").serialize(), //that's how you get data from your form to send your TrendVM to controller 
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#your-partial-view-container").html(data);
                }  
           });
    }); 
});
```

Now when you click on button your js code should be call controller and response will be added inside your `div`.